# Weblogic Websocket endpoint not working

Tags: java, websocket, weblogic

I'm trying to crete a simple Websocket application based on tutorial here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket004.htm

So the code looks something like this:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/echo")
public class EchoEndpoint {
   @OnMessage
   public void onMessage(Session session, String msg) {
      try {
         session.getBasicRemote().sendText(msg);
      } catch (IOException e) { ... }
   }
}
```

I'm running Weblogic 12c. I thought the annotation should be automatically picked up and websocket endpoint created on the address `localhost:8888/myApp/echo`, but when I try to connect there with this js test: http://www.websocket.org/echo.html, nothing happens. Also when I attach debugger, I see that the `EchoEndpoint` class was not loaded. What else should I do to make it running? I see nothing else in the Oracle tutorial

Comment: I have the same issue with WLS 12.2.1.3 wich supports jsr356, [see](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/WLPRG/websockets.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The Tyrus library requires a JEE7 container, Weblogic only supports JEE6.

Follow this tutorial to get websockets in Weblogic.
http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/websockets.htm

Comment: Hi. It works now when I use ```@WebSocket``` annotation instead of ```@ServerEndpoint```